# scrollable table, focus on row

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

[jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/aDahT/415/)
I have a table with scrollable body.
Data is bound using `knockout.js`. A single row from the body can be selected.
By default some row is selected. But this row can be in the bottom of the body, in which case the user can't see it. How can I make the selected row visible by default? I want to scroll the table to the selected row by default automatically when the page loads. The order of the data can't be changed.

Comment: Are you using jQuery, zepto, or other libraries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/aDahT/416/

```
var GetElementByClassName = function(matchClass){
  var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*'), i;
    for (i in elems) {
        if((' ' + elems[i].className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + matchClass + ' ')
                > -1) {
            return elems[i];
        }
    }  
};

GetElementByClassName('selectedRow').scrollIntoView(true);
```

If you want a more comprehensive `GetElementsByClass`, you can [check this out](http://robertnyman.com/2008/05/27/the-ultimate-getelementsbyclassname-anno-2008/). Newer browsers (see: not IE), have this baked in.